# Random Forest in R: intepret the plot

Tags: r, random-forest

I run random forest (using package randomForest) on the classic titanic data. Here are the code and results.

```
set.seed(123)
dt_rf <- randomForest(Survived ~ ., data = train, ntree = 500)
plot(dt_rf)
```

[image]

Wondering how shall I interpret the plot here. What does each line represent? Is it training, testing, and validation? If so, which one is which? And how does the `randomForest` function split the data?

Comment: Those are error rates which you will find in `dt_rf$err.rate` where the black line the OOB error while the red and green lines are for each of the two factors in your data.   Your code's `data = train` suggests this is just on the training set.

Comment: @Henry Thanks. How can I tell which line (green or red) is for which level for my factor Y variable?

Comment: Look at `head(dt_rf$err.rate)` which will give you the values on the left hand side of the chart.  The first factor will probably be the red line and the second green